# Decrypting HLS stream

Tags: video, encryption, streaming, hls

I have a continuous HLS livestream that is Widevine encrypted. I can play the stream in my browser, but I want to be able to play the stream locally on a device which does not support encryption.

The URL of the stream is formatted like this:

https://server.domain/playlist.m3u8?token=[token_in_hex]&min_bitrate=[0]&max_bitrate=[xxxxxx]

Now, my question is, how do I decrypt the stream? I've looked into shaka packager, which seems it should be able to do the job. However, I haven't been able to figure out how to do this. Anyone that can help me on this?

I don't fully understand the URL of the stream; what is the token used for?

Comment: Try if you can view it in VLC

Comment: No, that does not work. It keeps showing a loading animation in the timebar..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The presence of widevine is there to specifically prevent this. The only way to decrypt it to have the key. Windvine works with your computer to decode and render without giving you access to the key. It requires a component in you browser called the “Content decryption module”. You must eaither contact widevide to get a CDM for your platform of choice, or ask the content provider for the AES key.